# Is Boltzmann constant $k_B$ constant?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, physical-chemistry, physical-constants

I heard in a lecture that [Boltzmann constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant) $k_B$ is not constant in some special cases. Do you know the title of the article which contains this one? Do you think this idea is true?

Comment: Do you mean the [Stefan-Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_constant) or the [Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant)? The former *could* be variable if the [fine structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant#Is_the_fine-structure_constant_actually_constant.3F) is not a constant.

Comment: Boltzmann constant k=1.380 * 10^(-23)J/K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in detail [in this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0208093), the time variation of dimensional constants has no operational meaning.